# Maptools: Plotting different geographic groups with different colors

Tags: r, gis, ggmap, r-maptools

I have a dataset with biological groups and its geographic information:

> results2

```
ID  Latitude    Longitude
A   -3,5     -39,5833
A   -7,0167  -37,9667
A   -9,2258  -43,4631
B   -16,6667 -49,5
B   -15,4333 -55,75
B   -19,0333 -57,2167
C   -29,2    -58,1
C   -30      -59,5167
C   -34,5667 -59,1167
```

I used maptools for plotting these points on a map, here the code:

```
xlim<-c(min(results2$Longitude),max(results2$Longitude)) 
  ylim<-c(min(results2$Latitude),max(results2$Latitude))
  readShapeLines("americas_adm0.shp") -> shape
  plot(shape, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
  par(new=TRUE)
  ## vamos aqui!!
  pontos<- data.frame(results2$Longitude,results2$Latitude)
  colnames(pontos)=c("Longitude","Latitude")
  points(pontos$Longitude, pontos$Latitude, pch=16, col=2, cex=1)
```

But i dont know how to delimit polygons for each group, and change the color options of the studied groups.

Comment: My apologies, i did not explain well: I plotting the map and the points with "maptools": `xlim<-c(min(results2$Longitude),max(results2$Longitude)) 
  ylim<-c(min(results2$Latitude),max(results2$Latitude))
  readShapeLines("americas_adm0.shp") -> shape
  plot(shape, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
  par(new=TRUE)
  pontos<- data.frame(results2$Longitude,results2$Latitude)
  colnames(pontos)=c("Longitude","Latitude")
  points(pontos$Longitude, pontos$Latitude, pch=16, col=2, cex=1)`  But i dont know how to elaborate the polygons of each group.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "the polygons of each group" ? Are you perhaps refering to what is known as a "[convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)" : in this case quite a few GIS packages (such as sp) should supply the fiunctionality...